# How to Groupby and plot it

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by

I have the following dataframe (with different campaigns)

[image]

When I use groupby and try to plot, I get several graphs

```
df.groupby("Campaign").plot(y=["Visits"], x = "Week")
```

[image]

I would like to have only one graph with all the visits in the same graph by every campaign during the week time. Also because the graphs show up separated, I do not know which one belongs to each campaign.

I would appreciate any tips regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
df.set_index(['Week','Campaign'])['Visits'].unstack().plot(title='Visits by Campaign')
```

For multiple values of Week/Campaign let's aggregate them with `sum` or you could use `mean` to average the values:

```
df.groupby(['Week','Campaign'])['Visits'].sum().unstack().plot(title='Visits by Campain')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: @May You have duplicate weeks, campaings values.   What do you want to do add these visits together or average them?

Comment: all the campaigns have the same weeks from 1 to 30. I want to see how visits of every individual campaign are developing through the week time line

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution would be to use seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.lineplot(x="Week",
                  y="Visits",
                  hue="Campaign",
                  estimator=None,
                  lw=1,
                  data=df)
```

The documentation is [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)

Comment: I need start giving seaborn some love in my solutions too. +1

Comment: Yours was my first thought, but particularly with '0.9.0' there are a lot of nifty shortcuts that seaborn provides